# Expand dataframe based on values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3
 a   |   2  |  6
 a   |   1  |  3
 b   |   4  |  2
 b   |   2  |  3
```

Wish to expand it based on Col2 as a frequency. So Col2 means the combination of a-6 is repeated twice, like so:

```
Col1 | Col3 |
 a   |   6  |
 a   |   6  |
 a   |   3  |
 b   |   2  |
 b   |   2  |
 b   |   2  |
 b   |   2  |
 b   |   3  |
 b   |   3  |
```

Comment: What have you done to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just using `repeat` with `reindex`

```
df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df.Col2)).drop('Col2',1)
Out[443]: 
  Col1  Col3
0    a     6
0    a     6
1    a     3
2    b     2
2    b     2
2    b     2
2    b     2
3    b     3
3    b     3
```